# Let's ask Questions!

Tags: discussion, questions

We just dipped below the 5 questions per day mark again while maintaining a steady growth in users and keeping our views a day stable. People are visiting the site, but we seem to have a real problem generating questions. When we do get questions it seems that a good chunk of the time the question ends up making it into the [Hot Network Questions](http://stackexchange.com/questions?tab=hot) section which is great for attracting new users from other sites on SE.

I know there is a lot of people that visit the site every day that are active in the site. If everyone who was active posted a question just once a week I'm sure that we would have no problem making it over 5 questions asked per day. I also know we all don't know everything there is to know about music and all started out as beginners at one time. Did you every not understand something? Did you have a roadblock that you hit? Did you ever see another musician do or say something that you didn't understand? Most of those experiences can translate into a question that can be asked here. You can even answer your own question.

Not only will asking more questions get our questions per day numbers up but it will also encourage new users to participate and hopefully let us get more active users.

Answer (score 4):

I've been throwing in a few of the regular thoughts I have that I'm curious about and seeing what sticks.  If it turns out there's no interest I'll just clear it, but it's got some really cool knowledge back now and then.

Comment: Exactly. We need more people to do that. Every little bit helps.

Comment: You are a good resource here Alexander, both with questions and answers. Keep up the good work :)